# Find which element introduces horizontall scrollbar?

Tags: html, css, browser, responsive-design

When trying to make websites responsive I quite often get horizontal scrollbar on small widths. But often it is quite not obvious which element introduces it and it might take quite some time to pin down. It is even worse when it is interaction of multiple elements... So maybe someone can give some advice, of how to reliably find which elements flow incorrectly?

Comment: check my answer and let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 0):

You get a horizontal scroll bar when some element has width greater than its parent.

If problem is occurring in responsive design, elements which has `width` in `px` or `em` are probably the ones causing issue. Give them `width` in `%` and that might solve your issue.

Comment: This is overly simplistic. While it works I already do that, but it is quite time consuming. Especially when you have multiple areas of page with different parameters (overflow, items in menu blocks are mostly all right with fixed widths). Embedded content like google ads and similar. I I'm probably looking something more like a tool, (think object inspector addon, JavaScript bookmarklet or similar)